# Make eclipse copy groovy spring files rather than compile into class files

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, groovy

I am writing my first Spring application with Spring 4 groovy configuration. I am using Eclipse IDE. As usual I have all my Java files (actual domain/services etc.) in src/main/java and all my Spring Groovy configs in src/config/groovy.

Both are added as source to the classpath in Eclipse. As a result Eclipse compiles my groovy files into .class files and copies into target folder. But the problem is I am trying to load my Spring groovy classes from classpath as below, but it doesn't work as JVM can't find .groovy files as Eclipse compiled them into .class files.

```
def ctx = new GenericGroovyApplicationContext()
ctx.load("classpath:spring/SpringConfig.groovy")
```

Is there any way to force Eclipse not to compile my Spring groovy files but copy them to the output folder like xml files? For a test application I can probably use the file system path like "file:..." but I don't think I want to use it in PROD, so I am trying to write something that works both in IDE and PROD. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I should have looked around a bit hard! Resolved it myself.

In Eclipse, Go to Window->Preferences->Groovy->Compiler
Just check the option "Enable script folder support" and the pattern to cover the path where your groovy scripts are, then eclipse just copies them to the output folder like any other scripts.